# You have a set of N ranges, is it possible to find whether the intersection is empty in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, range

I have a set of N ranges, where each range is in the form of `[a,b]` and both `a`, `b` are integers.

I would like to find whether their intersection is empty.

Without assuming anything about this set, would it be possible to do something in O(n) time?

Comment: Numbers in the ranges, other than a and b are integers as well?

Comment: integers for simplicity

Comment: @JaviV Does that make a difference? If I'm not mistaken it is the same regardless of what you choose...

Comment: Well, you can find the intersection of two ranges in O(1) time, so the intersection of N ranges in O(N) time should be simple. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Kevin: if range A and range B intersect then you're done but if they don't intersect, how does the algorithm continue? With A or B? Or do you still need to check every possible intersection?

Comment: @SimeonVisser, you continue by finding the intersection of A, B, and C. If you saved A and B's intersection from the previous step, then this is also an O(1) operation.

Comment: @Kevin: but if A and B don't intersect then there is no intersection to compare with C. How do you then know whether C intersects with either A or B?

Comment: @SimeonVisser, If A and B don't intersect, then the algorithm is over. You print "the intersection of all these ranges is empty" and terminate the function. No comparison with C required.

Comment: @jsguy Do you want to find a range, that is an intersection of all renges? Or you want to find if any 2 ranges have an intersection?

Comment: @Kevin: If you fix `N`, then every problem of size `N` is `O(1)`. That line of reasoning is not helpful.

Comment: Yes Igor, a range that is the intersection of all ranges, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @rici, If you're referring to my "the intersection of two ranges is O(1)" comment, I'm not trying to "fix N". The logic works for any N. When N is 2, you need one intersection. When N is 100, you need 99 intersections. Therefore, it's O(N).

Comment: @kevin: yeah, once I figured out what you were asking, I answered accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual problem with N ranges is to determine whether they are pairwise disjoint (which is `O(N log N)`) but here I think you are asking whether the intersection of all the ranges is empty. That can be solved in `O(N)` in the obvious way:

1. Set `R` to the first range `R1`.
2. For each subsequent range `Ri`, set `R` to the intersection of itself with `Ri`
3. At the end, `R` will be the intersection. Check to see if it is empty.

That this works in `O(N)` relies on two facts:

1. You can intersect two ranges in `O(1)`.
2. The intersection of two ranges is either empty or a range.

Both of these fall directly out of the fact that the intersection of two ranges `[low1, high1]` and `[low2, high2]` is `[max(low1,low2), min(high1, high2)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try and see if the maximum of the lower limits is larger than the minimum of the upper limits. If the first is greater than the second, the intersection has to be empty. (If this is not obvious, I'll try to find or construct a proof.) If not, check if the resulting interval `[max, min]` contains elements of your choice (you didn't mention if you are looking for an interval in the integers, or real numbers, or what<sup>1</sup>.

Maximum and minimum of a list can both be found in linear time. So this will perform in O(N) time.

```
import numpy as np
ranges = np.array([[1, 5], [2, 3], [-1, 17], [15, 15]])

max = np.max(ranges[:,0])
min = np.min(ranges[:,1])

if max > min:
    print "definitely empty"
else:
    print "gotta check, but we've got the intersection now. it's [{0}:{1}]".format(max, min)
```

<sup>1</sup> For the typical kinds of sets, say, reals or integers, this check should be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

A1 ∩ A2 ∩ ..., ∩ An = ( ( ( A1 ∩ A2) ∩ A3 ) ∩ .... ∩ An )

You stop intersecting when you encounter an empty set. Each pair takes `O(1)`

Comment: How is this different from rici's answer?

Comment: @chepner I see now. mine has one line